# Arrange lists of lists on button click Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, nested-lists, custom-lists

I have data, two input fields with a button and on clicking the button I want to move the data to certain position:

i.e
**two input fields** = source and destination it's basically the indexes to move  a certain item from source to destination

data=

```
        {
      "0": [
        {
          "key": "Survey Meta Data"
        }
      ],
      "1": [
        {
          "key": "New Section"
        }
      ],
      "2": [
        {
          "key": "Tax Authority"
        }
      ]
    }
```

explaining what  I want
    the input field **source**=2**destination**=0
    now my  data will be

```
    {
  "0": [
    {
      "key": "Tax Authority"
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "key": "Survey Meta Data"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "key": "New Section"
    }
  ]
}
```

As it's moved to the first index and other items are pushed
any help will be greatly appreciated

**index.html**

```
Source=<input  ng-model="source" type="number>
Destination<input ng-model="destination" type="number>
<button ng-click="arrange(source,destination)></button>
{{model|json}}
```

**index.js**

```
$scope.model=[[{"key":'Survey Meta data'}],[{key:'New Section'}],[{key:Tax Authority'}]]

$scope.arrange(src,dest)
{
//trick to push
}
```

Comment: Check the answer below and see if that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use `splice` to achieve this.

**JS**:

```
   $scope.myObj = {
    "0": [{
        "key": "Survey Meta Data"
    }],
    "1": [{
        key: 'New Section'
    }],
    "2": [{
        "key": "Tax Authority"
    }]
};
$scope.model = [];
for (var i in $scope.myObj) {
    if ($scope.myObj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        $scope.model.push($scope.myObj[i]);
    }
}
Array.prototype.insert = function(index, item) {
    this.splice(index, 0, item);
};
$scope.arrange = function(src, dest) {
    var temp = [];
    temp = $scope.model.splice(parseInt(src), 1);
    $scope.model.insert(parseInt(dest), temp[0]);
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.model.length; i++) {
        $scope.myObj[i] = $scope.model[i];
    }
}
```

**Demo**:
http://jsfiddle.net/yj9sswq1/5/

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you heck the fiddle?

Comment: .splice is not a function\

Comment: You might be doing it the wrong way. try copy pasting the above code from working fiddle

Comment: my lists is this:

{ "0": [ { "key": "Survey Meta Data" } ], "1": [ { "key": "Tax Authority" } ] }

Comment: But in your question, you have defined like this $scope.model=[[{"key":'Survey Meta data'}],[{key:'New Section'}],[{key:Tax Authority'}]]

Comment: its just a mistake on code as my real world example is quite complicated that is just trying to explain you can see my model above

Comment: like the data I have declared above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148768/discussion-between-vivz-and-kumail-hussain).